# latexmk: does not clean lualatex[number].fls

Tags: latexmk

Running latexmk, I sometimes get files lualatex1234.fls.
Would be interesting where they come from.
Nevertheless, I want to erase
and so aded to `.latexmkrc`

```
$clean_ext .= " %R.synctex.gz %R.*.vrb lualatex17420.fls";
```

Beleave or not, whereas the synctex files are erased
and also the vrb files (coming from beamer class),
even though * represents arbitrary numbers,
the lualatex files are not erased.
I suspect, latexmk expects some placeholder or i dont know.

Maybe in latexmk another variable would be nice
holding the current processor,
so that I can write configs which also work for xelatex.

Answer (score 2):

The description for `$clean_ext` in the latexmk documentation explains all this.  The items in `$clean_ext` are either extensions of files to be removed (with the basename being that of the main .tex file), or contain the place holder `%R` (for the basename of the main .tex file).

There is at present no convenient way of getting latexmk to automatically remove the files like `lualatex17420.fls` that sometimes are generated when a *latex program is terminated prematurely.  (The integer in the filename is the process number of the process generating the file, so it will change from run to run.)  Latexmk is somewhat conservative about what files it automatically deletes, because of the danger of unexpectedly deleting files that have nothing to do with the current document.

Comment: you are right, I should have read the docs more carefully.
My apology is: i did read and in my mind was just the case with %R. 
Maybe the problem behind my misreading is that $clean_ext refers to both whole file names and extensions despite the name. 

In the other case I use push at generated_exts, "lol"; or that like.



Maybe a clear separation would be best: 
What do you think about at generated_files, which refer to whole file names taking %R into account if present.

Comment: Yes, the name `$clean_ext` is misleading. It's an issue of backward compatibility.  Originally, only extensions were allowed.  Then it became convenient to allow more general patterns, and at the time it seemed easiest to generalize the definition of `$clean_ext` to allow `%R` instead of adding another configuration variable.